# How to programmatically set the field formatter for a field given certain conditions

Tags: 8, entities

I have an entity 'house' with an address field. The address field comes with a default field formatter plugin. This is perfect for when i view my entity at its canonical route and where its view_mode is 'full'.

However I want to change how the address field is displayed when the 'house' has view_mode 'teaser'. For example at a page that displays a list of all my houses. To be specific I want my address to appear on one line.

Now, I have gotten all this working. Like this:

`house_entity/src/Plugin/Field/FieldFormatter/AddressTeaserFormatter`

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\rrre_entities\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter;

use Drupal\address\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\AddressPlainFormatter;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'address_teaser' formatter.
 *
 * @FieldFormatter(
 *   id = "address_teaser",
 *   label = @Translation("Teaser"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "address",
 *   },
 * )
 */
class AddressTeaserFormatter extends AddressPlainFormatter {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode) {
  $elements = parent::viewElements($items, $langcode);
  foreach ($elements as &$element) {
    $element['#theme'] = 'address_teaser';
  }
  return $elements;
}
```

`house_entity/house_entity.module`

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function house_entity_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [

    'house' => [
      'render element' => 'listing',
    ],

    'address_teaser' => [
      'variables' => [
        'recipient' => '',
        'organization' => '',
        'address_line1' => '',
        'address_line2' => '',
        'postal_code' => '',
        'sorting_code' => '',
        'dependent_locality' => [],
        'locality' => [],
        'administrative_area' => [],
        'country' => [],
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```

and in the same `house_entity.module` file:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function template_preprocess_house(&$variables) {
  $addressDisplayOptions = [
    'type' => 'address_teaser',
  ];
  $house->address->getItemDefinition()->getFieldDefinition()->setDisplayOptions('view', $addressDisplayOptions);
}
```

Finally I have my template for my new address fieldformatter all set up at `house_entity/templates/address-teaser.htm.twig`

This all works fine.

*Except* that the custom field formatter does not apply to the first 'house' in my list of 'houses' (it does apply to all subsequent 'houses') ... and adding a xdebug_break() immediately after the line:

`$listing->address->getItemDefinition()->getFieldDefinition()->setDisplayOptions('view', $addressDisplayOptions);`

Triggers the following error - basically that the twig template was not found:
[image: twig template not found]

Question?:

Do I have my template in the right place?
Is there a more convenient way of setting a field formatter for a particular field on an entity?

Comment: You have a typo (at least in what you typed in the question), your template path is set to `house_entity/templates/address-teaser.htm.twig` but should be `house_entity/templates/address-teaser.html.twig`, theres an `l` missing for **html** extension. Also I would recommend not to use iteration by reference as you do in your `::viewElements` method for the formmatter, its preferable to avoid this kind of iterations where possible.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a more convenient way of setting a field formatter for a particular field on an entity?

Yes, choose the formatter in the view mode settings (configure in the user interface) rather than using template preprocess.

(I found this old question looking for how to make a field formatter, and ended up copying [Drupal\user\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldFormatter%21UserNameFormatter.php/class/UserNameFormatter/8.5.x) and simplifying it by dropping the configuration parts, and then simply selecting that formatter on the view modes and Views tables i wanted to use it on.)

For ensuring this formatter doesn't show up in places it shouldn't, the key part is "isApplicable"; here's what mine looked like for a custom entity 'give_donation' and a field named 'recurring':

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function isApplicable(FieldDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
    return $field_definition->getTargetEntityTypeId() === 'give_donation' && $field_definition->getName() === 'recurring';
  }
```